# How to Bind selectAll event in TCL-TK for Linux

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit

```
bind $outputScolledText <Control-a> {
    event generate [keylget ::TKRESTGUI::GUIWIDGETS outputScolledText] <Control-/>
    break;
}
```

The above code is working fine in windows but not in Linux. **{bad event type or keysym "/"}**

Comment: instead of generating a new event, why not simply bind it to a function that does the select-all?

Answer (score 2):

For non-alphabetic keys, you need to use the name and not the character in such bindings. By far the easiest way to look up what the name is is to use this little Tk script:

```
package require Tk
bind . <Key> {puts %K}
catch {console show};   # For windows...
```

Run that and you'll get a blank window. Type the key into the blank window and the console will tell you what its name is. For `/`, it's called `slash`.